# NinjectWebCommon.cs not getting latest version from VS2015 TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

Our team is working on a single project and solution that utilizes Ninject MVC5. We have a NinjectWebCommon.cs file located in our 'App_Start' folder that contains our bindings to the interfaces and repositories. When we check-in this file into TFS, the changes that were checked-in are not showing up. We have confirmed several times that it has been checked-in with changes and we have even overwrote our existing version to ensure we're getting the most current version (with no luck).

Any idea why this is happening? And how do we go about fixing this without re-typing our NinjectWebCommon.cs file over-and-over again?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot get the remote version from TFS, or the changes are not really checked in? Please check if the changes showing up in code tab via web portal? If it is, just try to clean the caches both for TFS and VS, then check it again. If the doesn't work, try creating a new workspace and map to another folder, then try it again. Also, please check if this issue occurs on other VS clients.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT - Thank you. I was not able to get the remote version from TFS. The changes were really checked in and we confirmed this via 'Version History'. We eventually solved the problem and I will post the solution in case it happens to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation happened to two programmers who were unable to retrieve the latest version of the NinjectWebCommon.cs checked into TFS. To resolve the problem, we compared what we saw in our 'Solution Explorer' and 'Source Control Explorer'.

In our 'Solution Explorer', the file existed and appeared checked-in as the latest version. Closer inspection in the 'Source Control Explorer', though, revealed that the file was marked checked-out with the pending change of 'delete'. How and why the 'delete' action was applied to file may be related to the uninstall and reinstall of the Ninject.MVC4 nuget package, however, we cannot confirm nor deny that this is true.

The only solution we found to resolve the issue and obtain the changes in TFS was to actually check-in the file while it was marked 'delete', which then resulted in TFS identifying whether to take the 'Workspace Version' or 'Server Version' - I took the 'Server Version'.

Everything seemed to work fine from then on.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT - thanks, Andy! I'm still learning the ropes of Stack Overflow and I appreciate these pointers that could help other developers!